# Chrome bug rendering fonts in Angular 2 projects

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, fonts

I have a problem rendering fonts in chrome with requests that returns 304.

Look at the following cases:

**Case 1:**

[image: Bad rendering]
[image: Fonts loading with 304 http code]

**Case 2:**

[image]
[image]

This only happens in Chrome. It's tested in Safari, Firefox and Edge. All browsers renders the font with 304.

Another hint I can tell you is that if I open Chrome dev tools, and uncheck a random style property and recheck it again (this property doesn't have to belong to this component, for example, I can uncheck body -> background-color), the font is rendered properly.

BUT, All of this only happens if the page is loaded and you change the url. For example, I'm in home page /, and click a link to go to /foo, if the font just loaded in that moment with 304, then it won't rendered by chrome. If I load /foo and press Reload the whole page, the font is rendered.

Any idea?
Is it a known issue?
Is an Angular issue?
Is a Chrome issue?

All ideas are welcome.